# How to test whether a dataset exists in HDF5 file before attempting to open it?

Tags: r, hdf5

I have the following snippet that works OK but generates an unwanted error if the dataset "Test" does not exist in the hdf5 file which is, in fact, a valid case:

```
library(rhdf5)
test_data <- h5read('test.h5', 'Test')
if (exists('test_data')) {
   # then read the data
   df_test <- as.data.frame(t(test_data))
   # work with df_test 
}
```

and R outputs an error if the dataset does not exist:

```
 Error in h5read('test.h5', 'Test') : 
   Object Test does not exist in this HDF5 file.
 Execution halted
```

I would like to gracefully handle this without the R process spitting out sporadic errors.

Comment: Maybe use `trycatch` ? I suspect part of your confusion is that `h5read` is the function which is looking for `Test` , so if it fails, that happens before `test_data` even gets created.

Comment: Indeed using trycatch elegantly solves my OP. Can you please provide a good quality answer based on trycatch and I will accept? The working snippet to replace the first line with would be: `tryCatch(test_data <- h5read('test.h5', 'Test'), error = function(e) { print("'Test' dataset not found") })` the rest of the code remains as is since the `exists` function will do its job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think, based on your comments, that this is the line you want:

Let's assume you've entered the file name as an argument, so:

```
nextfile<- 'test.h5'

tryCatch(test_data <- h5read(nextfile, 'Test'), error = function(e) { print(paste("'Test' dataset not found in ",nextfile)) })
```

Then you'll know which file(s) failed.  (presumably you have a similar mechanism set up to store each file in a different "test_data" or an element of a list variable `test_data[[j]]`

Answer (score 0):

For those (like me) who were looking for this but in Python, you can simply check if the name of the dataset is in the file like this (with "Test" the name of the searched dataset):

```
import h5py
with h5py.File("/path/myfile.h5", "r") as h5fout:
   if "Test" in h5fout:
      print("The Test dataset is in the file")
```

Basically, using `in` will explore `h5fout` as if it was the list of the names of the datasets contained in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way is to use function `H5Lexists`:

```
library(rhdf5)

h5f <- H5Fopen("test.h5", flags="H5F_ACC_RDONLY")

if (H5Lexists(h5f, "Test")) {
    test_data <- h5read(h5f, "Test")
    // ...
}

H5Fclose(h5f)
```

It's better not to use exceptions for logic, especially in R with its poor exception system design.